# How to initialize a function in Qiskit with 3 qubit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, initialization

I would like to know how I can make an initialization with 3 qubits
to get  |000> ,|100> , |111>  ( 1 qubit --> |000> , |ψ⟩ = |000⟩ ⊗ |100⟩ ⊗ |111⟩)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $A^2 + B^2 + C^2 = 1$

```
temp = QuantumCircuit(3)
temp.initialize([A, 0, 0, 0, B, 0, 0, C])
```

where I've put A, B, and C into the spots corresponding to 0, 4, and 7 respectively.  As an example:

```
temp = QuantumCircuit(3)
temp.initialize([1/2, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 1/sqrt(2)])
Statevector(temp)
```

[image]